# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testing' While trying to execute unittest case in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, airflow, python-unittest

I have written a test case for my Python-airflow project, but while executing the command it is throwing `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testing'`

Complete error stack is -

```
ERROR: testing (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testing'
```

To execute the test case I am using command - `python -m unittest testing.unit_tests.alembic_unittest`

Here is my project structure -

```
project directory
├── testing
    ├── __init__.py
        ├
        └── unit_tests
            ├── __init__.py
            └── alembic_unittest.py
```

Inside project_directory/testing/**init**.py I have added syspath like

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'testing/')
```

But still I am getting this error. What could be the reason ?

```
PYTHONPATH=/Users/myname/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10:
```

I am using PyCharm IDE.

Comment: So, let me get this straight... You have a `testing` package. And in order for Python to find it, you have code **inside that same package** to add the `testing` directory to your `PYTHONPATH`? I think that might be the reason. In general, you may want to read up on the basics of how Python finds modules. There are literally thousands of questions on this site about issues with this and most of them arise because people don't understand the basics of module imports.

Answer (score 1):

You should be in `project directory` for that python command to work. If it doesn't, try removing the `__init__.py` files from your test folders. I don't think that `unittest` imports the test classes the same way that regular imports happen.